# How to get the value from dropdowns and insert into MySQL Workbench?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, mysql-workbench

After I selected one item of the drop-down list, the selected option doesn't show in MySQL Workbench (version 8).

The provided code below (php code included) in my tables called `crimenews` and `crimetypes`, there are many other columns but my problem is the selected option doesn't show in MySQL Workbench.

**Connect.php**

```
<?php 
      $server = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"; //xxx=number
      $username = "xxx";
      $password = "xxx";
      $dbname = "xxx";
      //Establish database connection
      $conn = new mysqli($server, $username, $password, $dbname);
      if($conn->connect_error)
      {
        die("Connection failed: ". $conn->connect_error);
      }
?>
```

**Front.php** *(Main page)*

*Already include connect.php*

```
<form method="post" action="add.php"><center style="color: #FFFFC9 ; font-family: Arial">     
        <b>Category: </b> 
        <select name="catagory">
        <?php
            $type = "SELECT crime_type FROM crimetypes";
            $qry = mysqli_query($conn,$type);
            while($fin = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qry))
            {
        ?>  <option value="<?php echo($fin["crime_type"]);?>"><?php echo($fin["crime_type"]);?></option>
        <?php            
            }
        ?>                      
        </select>
        <b>URL: </b> <input type="url" name="url" placeholder="URL (www.)"><br><br>
        <b>Date: </b> <input type="datetime-local" name="datetime"><br><br>               
        <b>Latitude: </b> <input type="text" name="lat" placeholder="Latitude"><br><br>
        <b>Longitude: </b> <input type="text" name="lng" placeholder="Longitude"><br><br>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Add"> //Submit button 
</form>
```

**Add.php**

*Already include connect.php*

```
    //For adding news
    $category = $_POST['category']; 
    $url = $_POST['url'];
    $datetime = $_POST['datetime'];
    $lat = $_POST['lat'];
    $lng = $_POST['lng'];
    $sql = "INSERT INTO crimenews (crimenews_type, crimenews_url, crimenews_date, crimenews_locationLat, crimenews_locationLong) VALUES ('$category', '$url', '$datetime', '$lat', '$lng')";

    if($conn->query($sql) === TRUE)
    {
        header("location: front.php");
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Error!";
    }
```

**crimetype table in MySQL Workbench**

```
    crimetype_id|crime_type
    ------------|-----------
            1   | A
            2   | B
                 .
                 .
                 .
```

**crimenews table in MySQL Workbench** *(This actually happened)*

```
crimenews_id|crimenews_type|crimenews_url|crimenews_date|crimenews_locationLat|crimenews_locationLong
------------|--------------|-------------|--------------|---------------------|----------------------
        1   |              |             |              |                     |
        2   |              |             |              |                     |
                           .
                           .
                           .
```

**Here is expected result in MySQL Workbench (crimenews table)**

```
crimenews_id|crimenews_type|crimenews_url|crimenews_date|crimenews_locationLat|crimenews_locationLong
------------|--------------|-------------|--------------|---------------------|----------------------
        1   |       A      |             |              |                     |
        2   |       B      |             |              |                     |
                           .
                           .
                           .
```

How to get the value in crime_type from `crimetypes` table and insert into `crimenews` table in crimenews_type?

Comment: `...(other columns)` - please do not show us psuedo-code, show us your actual code.

Comment: `INSERT INTO database` you do not have a table called `database`

Comment: I already edited and added more coded with some spelling check, thank you. @GrumpyCrouton

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your select name is `catagory` and in the `$_POST`, you have it as `category`. You have to change that.